# MongoDB Aggregation: How to push a string onto an array for the entire collection

Tags: arrays, mongodb, push, aggregation

I have a collection like so...

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "r3d4ct3d"
  },
  "name": "david doan",
  "dateAdded": "2023-07-21T22:15:13.199Z",
  "email": "dave@gmail.com",
  "state": "New York",
  "tags": [
    "tag 1",
    "tag 2"
  ],
}
```

And all I want to do is push a string `tag 3` onto the `tags` array without having to leave the aggregation pipeline in Compass. I don't want to have to create an app just to insert a string, so `.update()` is out of the question.

How do I do this without building an entire app for it?

I've tried using `$set`, but that doesn't allow me to use `$push` and the `$reduce` operator was too complicated for me. ‍♂️

I've tried using `$group`, but then I don't get the right projection and I don't want to have to copy the entire schema just to add a tag.

Comment: *without building an entire app for it*, with MongoDB Compass, it provides CLI to allow executing the query. For update query, it should be: `db.Contact.update({}, { $addToSet: { tags: "tag 3"} }, { multi: true })`

Answer (score 0):

After careful examination, I've found that you can just concatenate the array from the original document with the new value by setting the array to a `$concatArrays` of itself and the value that you want to push onto that array.

```
[
  {
    '$set': {
      'tags': {
        '$concatArrays': [
          '$tags', [
            'test'
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$merge': {
      'into': 'Contact'
    }
  }
]
```